# Pull up the most recent record including joining 2 tables and filters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have seen a lot of posts on pulling up the most recent record. I haven't been able to find one that includes joining another table and filters.

What I need is information regarding the most recent document (record) created, but only if it meets certain criteria. PLUS I need to pull in some data from another table.

s504Plans Table

```
    Student ID   |   Firstname   |   Startdate   |   Status
    ----------       ---------       ---------       ------
    111111            Johnny         1/5/2015          F
    222222            Sue            4/7/2016          I
    333333            Barb           2/5/2016          F
    111111            Johnny         2/1/2016          F
```

Cases Table

```
    Student ID   |   School   |   
    ----------       ------
    111111           Franklin
    222222           Eisenhower
    333333           Franklin
```

And the results I'd like to see are only the most recent document where the status of the document is F...

```
    Student ID  |  Firstname  |  Startdate  |  Status  |   School
    ----------     ---------     ---------     ------      ------
    111111          Johnny       2/1/2016        F         Franklin
    333333          Barb         2/5/2016        F         Franklin
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inner join and where

```
select 
    a.Student_ID
  , a.Firstname
  , a.Startdate
  , a.Status
  , b.School
from s504Plans  as a
inner join Cases  as b on  a.Student_ID = b.Student_ID
inner join ( select Student_ID, max(Startdate ) as max_startdate
            from s504Plans
            group by Student_ID) t 
           on ( a.Student_id = t.Student_id and a.Startdate = t.max_startdate)
where a.Status = 'F'
```

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't sure about order of operations and whether or not it would pull the most recent regardless of the status FIRST and then remove any of the most recents marked Inactive which might have left a few kids out.  I'll give this a try now!

Comment: I ended up getting some error messages.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 7 No column name was specified for column 2 of 't'.  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 Invalid column name 'startdate'.

Comment: I've looked through time and again and can't see a mis-type on my end.  I'll keep looking!

Comment: @bosstone75    missing alias for max(Startdate) .. i have update the answer

Comment: Whoo hoo!  Success!  Thanks!

Comment: Done.  It won't let me publically upvote as well although I did it and it said it was recorded.